# Numpy Nested Arrays by reference Inside array element but not a 3 dim arrary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

** Problem **

How to refence Numpy nested arrays by reference inside array elements? When the elements on not, NOT, as 3 dim array, but the results of a `list(map(lambda))` on elements to assign a rank, eg., `['g',e','f','a','b','c']`. Perhaps need to convert to structure and allows `[1][0][1]...[7][0][1]` refencing approach.

** Goal Needed Report on rank **
Need to report on rank, eg., `['g',e','f','a','b','c']`
But `array([1,2,3,4]), array([.4, .5, .6]) AKA [1][0]...[7][0]` works but NOT `[1][0][1]...[7][0][1]`

** Code effort try **

started with np.array()::

```
array_things = np.array(data_head[;, 1-8]).sum(axis=1, float)
```

then next after a np.vectorized() AND and then a list(map) ::

```
np.vectorized(funA) 
list(map(lambda x: funB(x), array_things))
```

This `list(map(labda x: funB(x), array_things))` assigns the ['g',e','f','a','b','c'] associated to the [1][0],...[1][1]...[7][0],...[7][1]. Something like a simple rank but not as a 3 dim array [1][0][1]...[7][0][1]

** Effort **

```
array_data[1][0]
array_data[1][1]
```

but need to reference the, say [1][0][1]

** Logical Data **
If the np.array as the basic data output layout as such, eg:

```
array([1,2,3,4]), array([.4, .5, .6]), (['g','e','f'])
```

example data :

```
(array([1,2,3,4,5]), array([.55, .65, .76,.81,.79]),(['g',e','f','a','b','c'])
```

Comment: Pragmatically, what is the structure : (array([]), array([]), ([])  and how does one reference the , ([]) at the far right of the structure?

Comment: I tried to clean up the formatting but your goal and code still isn't clear.  Why are you trying to work with arrays, "nested" or not.  It might be clearer if you stuck with lists.

Comment: thanks,  sorry bout code formt...

Comment: trying to reference (['g','e','f']) assigned by lambda x: funB(x), array_things) inside ARRAY structure :::: array([1,2,3,4]), array([.4, .5, .6]), (['g','e','f']), what would be the CAST to np.arrary to.list? This person I am working with needs to work on np.array... but yes, list would work easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also found a solution using Numpy.atleast_2d(1, [1, 2], [[1, 2]]) which was able to work with the (array([1,2,3,4,5]), array([.55, .65, .76,.81,.79]),(['g',e','f','a','b','c'])

Answer (score 1):

The data tuple:

```
In [4]: np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([.55, .65, .76,.81,.79]),['g','e','f','a','b','c']
Out[4]: 
(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([0.55, 0.65, 0.76, 0.81, 0.79]),
 ['g', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
```

object dtype array from that:

```
In [5]: arr = np.array(_, object)    
In [6]: arr
Out[6]: 
array([array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([0.55, 0.65, 0.76, 0.81, 0.79]),
       list(['g', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c'])], dtype=object)    
In [7]: arr.shape
Out[7]: (3,)
```

If the arrays/lists are all the same size this isn't a reliable constructor.

Access to one of the elements, the last list:

```
In [8]: arr[2]
Out[8]: ['g', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Selecting a element of that list:

```
In [9]: arr[2][0]
Out[9]: 'g'
```

Selecting a sublist - normal list slice indexing:

```
In [10]: arr[2][:3]
Out[10]: ['g', 'e', 'f']
```

The other elements are arrays, so we can use 'advanced' indexing on those

```
In [11]: arr[1][[4,3,4,1]]
Out[11]: array([0.79, 0.81, 0.79, 0.65])
```

All of this would work just as well on the original tuple (or list) of arrays and list.  An object dtype array is nearly the same as a list.